# Counting output repeat

Tags: php, count

```
<?php
// public trailer config
// trailer-config.php
$title = "What_I_am_looking_for";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// select statement
$sql = "SELECT * from SEARCHTABLE where WHAT-I-AM-LOOKING-FOR ='$title' ";
// result from select statement in groups of 4
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $count=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $count++;
        if ($count % 4 == 0) {
            echo 'NOT FIRST RECORD';
        } else {
            echo 'FIRST RECORD';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '0 results',"\n";
}
?>
```

I need the output to be FIRST-RECORD the 3 NOT-FIRST-RECORDS then repeat. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Code indentation goes a long way to make your code readable and more inportantly **debuggable**

Comment: The code works. It just gives me:
NOT FIRST RECORD
NOT FIRST RECORD
NOT FIRST RECORD
FIRST RECORD

Comment: I need it to give me: FIRST RECORD NOT FIRST RECORD NOT FIRST RECORD NOT FIRST RECORD

Comment: Your condition is incorrect.change it to `if ($count % 4 != 0)`